# Android HTML Parse and Find

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have a HTML contents like this, I want to parse and extract a XML link from this content for a particular city, example I want to get the XML link for the city Acton, MA can anyone help me on this

```
<table class="area_links">
<tr>
    <td ><a type="application/rss+xml" target="_blank" href="http://test.com/cache/rss/tx-abilene.xml" title="Abilene, TX RSS Feed">Abilene, TX</a></td>
    <td ><a type="application/rss+xml" target="_blank" href="http://test.com/cache/rss/mi-garden-city.xml" title="Garden City, MI RSS Feed">Garden City, MI</a></td>
    <td class="neighborhood"><a type="application/rss+xml" target="_blank" href="http://test.com/cache/rss/orlando-lake-cherokee.xml" title="Lake Cherokee, Orlando RSS Feed">Lake Cherokee, Orlando</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td ><a type="application/rss+xml" target="_blank" href="http://test.com/cache/rss/ma-abington.xml" title="Abington, MA RSS Feed">Abington, MA</a></td>
   <td ><a type="application/rss+xml" target="_blank" href="http://test.com/cache/rss/ca-garden-grove.xml" title="Garden Grove, CA RSS Feed">Garden Grove, CA</a></td>
   <td class="neighborhood"><a type="application/rss+xml" target="_blank" href="http://test.com/cache/rss/orlando-lake-dot.xml" title="Lake Dot, Orlando RSS Feed">Lake Dot, Orlando</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td ><a type="application/rss+xml" target="_blank" href="http://test.com/cache/rss/ma-acton.xml" title="Acton, MA RSS Feed">Acton, MA</a></td>
   <td ><a type="application/rss+xml" target="_blank" href="http://test.com/cache/rss/co-garfield-county.xml" title="Garfield County, CO RSS Feed">Garfield County, CO</a></td>
    <td class="neighborhood"><a type="application/rss+xml" target="_blank" href="http://test.com/cache/rss/orlando-orlando-executive.xml" title="Orlando Executive, Orlando RSS Feed">Orlando Executive, Orlando</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td ><a type="application/rss+xml" target="_blank" href="http://test.com/cache/rss/co-adams-county.xml" title="Adams County, CO RSS Feed">Adams County, CO</a></td>
   <td ><a type="application/rss+xml" target="_blank" href="http://test.com/cache/rss/garland.xml" title="Garland, TX RSS Feed">Garland, TX</a></td>
   <td class="neighborhood"><a type="application/rss+xml" target="_blank" href="http://test.com/cache/rss/orlando-windhover.xml" title="Windhover, Orlando RSS Feed">Windhover, Orlando</a></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried this but its not coming correctly
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("Acton, MA").get();
                org.jsoup.nodes.Element content = doc.select(").first();
                Log.d("content",content.toString());

Comment: +1 for Jsoup, I use it for webpage parsing, perhaps you could provide us the web address you are trying to parse?

Comment: This is the URL I am trying to parse http://www.spotcrime.com/rss.php since the contents are too large, I want to make it fast and also extract the City related XML properly